# StreamReader ReadLine function

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, floating-point

I'm using a StreamReader object's ReadLine function to read decimal values from a text file.  What I find odd is some values have three decimal places of all zeroes, i.e "-93.000", but when I'm debugging, I notice the stream reader will only read the previous value as "-93.00".  I'm not sure why this happens, it will read values with two decimal places of all zeroes, i.e. "-85.00", just fine.  I need to be able to read the entire value for validation purposes, otherwise inaccurate results are reported in my program.

Any ideas why this behavior occurs?  Is there some other way of parsing the text file that will preserve the original string??  Thanks.

UPDATE:

Code that reads text file

```
string Line = sr.ReadLine();
```

Sample values, in the text file:

```
-93.000 {\Tab}
-99.99 {\Tab}
-85.00
```

Line variable after reading first line:

```
Line = "-93.00\t
-99.99\t
-85.00"
```

UPDATE 2:

I've stepped through this several times in the last hour.  I've tried to observant of where the Line is being set, this is what I've narrowed it down to.  I'll comb through the code again just to be sure.  I'll also look at the formatting of the text file as it was provided to me by an external source.

UPDATE 3:

Per John Saunders' suggestion, I tried it with the just the culprit value and lo and behold it provided the value as originally presented.  I'm guessing that it may have something to do with the way the original text file is formatted, maybe some hidden characters that are somehow affecting how the value is being read.  I know this is an unusual case.

UPDATE 4:

Tried modifying the text file in Notepad++, removed some spaces and resaved.  The stream reader now reads it fine.  This was a very strange issue and I do agree with everyone else that ReadLine() shouldn't have done this.  Perhaps it was also just a fluke with my settings or with the text file encoding.

Comment: The `ReadLine` method has no idea what the type of data is. Please show the code you use to get the numbers.

Comment: This cannot be from the `string ReadLine()`. I think you have to  convert to double before seeing things like that.

Comment: It's got to be the way you're splitting the values in your code. `ReadLine` would **never** do this sort of thing to us developers!

Comment: Agreed, lets get some contextual code, like your entire file parsing function please

Comment: Try it with a file containing only that first line.

Comment: It must be something else. Perhaps something simple yet easy to overlook like you're reading a different file than the file you think you're reading? Try changing the values in the text file completely to check.

Comment: Also, check the file with a hex editor to make sure there are no strange hidden unicode characters.

Comment: Great. Now that you've got it working with one line, add one more.

Comment: Are you sure those were spaces? Did you try the suggestion of looking at the file in hex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try reading the file via a `FileStream` as an array of bytes?

```
byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes( @"c:\foo\bar\bazbat.txt" ) ;
```

That's got to be some sort of encoding issue (e.g., your trying to read it as UTF-8 encoded text and the file is actually encoded with some other encoding.).

Comment: Thanks Nick, and I agree it was probably some strange encoding issue with the text file, as once I resaved in Notepad++ the issue seemed to be resolved.  I'll do some more analysis on my own.  I'll keep you above suggestion as an alternative for future projects.